# Merge two arrays in Ruby by unique key

Tags: arrays, ruby

How can I merge two arrays with the unique `key`:

```
keyList = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

keyValueList = [
  ["a", [1, 2, 3]],
  ["a", [4, 5, 6]],
  ["b", [5, "a", 3]],
  ["b", ["test", 4, 3]],
  ["c", [1, "number", 110]]
]
```

to get the following?

```
[
  ["a", [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]],
  ["b", [[5, "a", 3], ["test", 4, 3]]],
  ["c", [[1, "number", 110]]]
]
```

Comment: Please, show us what you have tried.

Comment: Hint: `group_by` looks useful here

Comment: The logic in the question is not clear. What is `keyList` doing?

Comment: What are the rules for merging these arrays into the final structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
keyValueList.
  map(&:flatten).
  group_by(&:shift).
  select { |k, _| keyList.include?(k) }.
  to_a
#⇒ [["a", [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]],
#   ["b", [[5, "a", 3], ["test", 4, 3]]],
#   ["c", [[1, "number", 110]]]
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear why the array `keyList` is needed.

```
keyValueList.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) do |(k,arr),h|
  h[k] << arr
end.to_a
  #=> [["a", [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]],
  #    ["b", [[5, "a", 3], ["test", 4, 3]]],
  #    ["c", [[1, "number", 110]]]]
```

`h[k] << arr` could be changed to `h[k]  << arr if keyList.include?(k)` if needed for the desired behavior.

The above could alternatively be written as follows.

```
keyValueList.each_with_object({}) do |(k,arr),h|
  (h[k] ||= []) << arr
end.to_a
```

Comment: This does not answer “merge two arrays” part though.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin It's the OP's fault. The question is not clear.

Comment: @sawa I surely do not blame Cary. The whole question was so poor-stated (and even poor-formatted) that I posted the answer literally out of pity. I am just pointing this out.

Answer (score 4):

```
keyValueList
.group_by(&:first)
.transform_values{|a| a.map(&:last)}
.to_a
# => [
#  ["a", [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]],
#  ["b", [[5, "a", 3], ["test", 4, 3]]],
#  ["c", [[1, "number", 110]]]
# ]
```

Comment: This is the best answer here so far.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin But I think OP is working with `ruby` & `transform_values` is rails specific.

Comment: @ray Not at all [since 2.4.0](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin my bad, I will take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though it does not appear in the expected result, I'd also take `keyList` into account, just in case, so:

```
keyList
.each_with_object({}) { |k, h| h[k] = keyValueList.select { |x, y| x == k }.map(&:last) }
.to_a

#=> [["a", [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]], ["b", [[5, "a", 3], ["test", 4, 3]]], ["c", [[1, "number", 110]]], ["d", []]]
```

To get rid of `["d", []]`, just append `.reject{ |e| e.last.empty? }`.